# How to create tuples ranging from (0,0,0) to (2,2,2), with the entry at most 2?

Tags: python

In Python, I want to create a tuple of tuples ranging from `(0,0,0)` to `(2,2,2)` with the entry at most 2. That is, I want to make `((0,0,0), (0,0,1), (0,0,2), (0,1,0), (0,1,1), (0,1,2), (0,2,0), ..., (2,1,2), (2,2,0), (2,2,1), (2,2,2))`.

But this has to cover the general situation. The computer has to automatically do this given any two nonnegative integers, one representing the length of each tuples, and the other representing the maximal entry of each tuples. For example, if I give 2 as the length of each tuples and 1 as the maximal entry, then the computer should produce `((0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1))`. Please help me with this. I'm using Python 3.

Comment: Is(0,2,2) difference from (2,2,0)?

Comment: @PraysonW.Daniel Yes, it is different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use itertools product like this:

```
from itertools import product

def createListOfTuple(arr,length):
    return [i for i in product(arr,repeat=length)]

print(createListOfTuple([0,1,2],3))
```

Comment: You beat me! You were so fast

Answer (score 6):

Dion was faster than me in response. So I will have to add more explanation.

Your problem is what itertools are made for. Dealing with iteratables. So taking time reading itertools documentation will payoff :https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html

Two functions are of interest to your cause depend on what behavior  you are after:

```
print(tuple(itertools.combinations_with_replacement((0,1,2),3) ))

print(tuple(itertools.product((0,1,2), repeat=3)))
```

product will allow 0,2,2 and 2,2,0 as different sequences ;)

per document:

> itertools.product(*iterables, repeat=1) Cartesian product of input
>   iterables.
>
> Roughly equivalent to nested for-loops in a generator expression. For
>   example, product(A, B) returns the same as ((x,y) for x in A for y in
>   B).
>
> The nested loops cycle like an odometer with the rightmost element
>   advancing on every iteration. This pattern creates a lexicographic
>   ordering so that if the input’s iterables are sorted, the product
>   tuples are emitted in sorted order.
>
> To compute the product of an iterable with itself, specify the number
>   of repetitions with the optional repeat keyword argument. For example,
>   product(A, repeat=4) means the same as product(A, A, A, A).